# Why is the flux 0? I don't understand this concept

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/7078/gaussl.jpg!

Why does it say that the flux due to q_2 and q_3 through S is 0? Doesn't it contain a nonzero charge q_1?

Does anyone also know the difference between "no charge" vs "net charge is 0"? My book differentiates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surface $\mathrm{S}$ does indeed contain charge $q_1$, and so will have nonvanishing electric flux. However, $\mathrm{S}$ does not contain charges $q_2$ and $q_3$, so it will have zero total flux *due to those charges*.